# Drag&Drop. Запрет перетаскивать в другие блоки

Tags: javascript, html, drag-n-drop

Как запретить перетаскивать в остальные ячейки, кроме одного? 
Например, 1 - только к красному, 2 - зеленому, 3 - синему.

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

```css
div#div1 {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    min-width: 75px;
    min-height: 75px;
    background-color: red;
}
div#div2 {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    min-width: 75px;
    min-height: 75px;
    background-color: green;
}
div#div3 {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    min-width: 75px;
    min-height: 75px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div style="overflow: hidden;">
<div style="width: 100%;">
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<div id="div3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
</div>
</div>

<img id="drag1" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/188/188234.svg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="70" height="70">
<img id="drag2" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/188/188235.svg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="70" height="70">
<img id="drag3" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/188/188236.svg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="70" height="70">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вызов [preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API/Drag_operations#droptargets) в обработчике `dragenter` или `dragover` указывает на то, что в данном месте можно закончить перетаскивание.

Таким образом в `allowDrop` нужно вызывать `ev.preventDefault()` не всегда, а только тогда, когда перетаскивается нужный элемент.

Получить перетаскиваемый элемент из dataTransfer нельзя, однако можно сохранить его в переменную по событию dragstart.

В результате код может выглядеть так:

```js
var dragged = null;
function allowDrop(ev) {
  if (ev.target.id == 'div' + dragged.id.match(/\d+/)) {
    ev.preventDefault();
  }
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
  dragged = ev.target;
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  dragged = null;
}
```

```css
div#div1 {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  min-width: 75px;
  min-height: 75px;
  background-color: red;
}

div#div2 {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  min-width: 75px;
  min-height: 75px;
  background-color: green;
}

div#div3 {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  min-width: 75px;
  min-height: 75px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div style="overflow: hidden;">
  <div style="width: 100%;">
    <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div id="div3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<img id="drag1" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/188/188234.svg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="70" height="70">
<img id="drag2" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/188/188235.svg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="70" height="70">
<img id="drag3" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/188/188236.svg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="70" height="70">
```

Comment: для мобильных как можно сделать чтобы заработал? в мобильных не работает почему-то. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/929892/dragdrop-%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82