# Drag&Drop. Запрет перетаскивать в другие блоки в мобильном не работает

Tags: javascript, html, drag-n-drop

В десктопе работает перетаскивание в определенно место, а в мобильном перестает работать.

```js
var dragged = null;
function allowDrop(ev) {
  if (ev.target.id == 'div' + dragged.id.match(/\d+/)) {
    ev.preventDefault();
  }
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
  dragged = ev.target;
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  dragged = null;
}
```

```css
div#div1 {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  min-width: 75px;
  min-height: 75px;
  background-color: red;
}

div#div2 {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  min-width: 75px;
  min-height: 75px;
  background-color: green;
}

div#div3 {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  min-width: 75px;
  min-height: 75px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawcdn.githack.com/Bernardo-Castilho/dragdroptouch/73802ba9d95326761e0361117ea312510d4a6a9b/DragDropTouch.js"></script>

<div style="overflow: hidden;">
  <div style="width: 100%;">
    <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div id="div3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<img id="drag1" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/188/188234.svg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="70" height="70">
<img id="drag2" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/188/188235.svg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="70" height="70">
<img id="drag3" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/188/188236.svg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="70" height="70">
```

Предыдущий вопрос: [Drag&Drop. Запрет перетаскивать в другие блоки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/929663/dragdrop-%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8)

Comment: Поставьте `allowDrop` на `ondragenter` событие тоже.

Comment: <img id="drag1" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/188/188234.svg" draggable="true" ondragenter="allowDrop(event)" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="70" height="70"> так?

Comment: Типа того. Мне сложно проверить на мобильном устройстве, поэтому попробуйте так и отпишитесь, получилось или нет.

Comment: Нет, не работает. Через chrome проверяю. В десктопном режиме все работает, а когда переключаюсь к мобильному виду, перестает работать, к любому блоку можно перетаскивать.

Comment: Погодите, вы проверяете не на мобильном устройстве, а на десктопе в эмуляции мобильного устройства?

Comment: В мобильном тоже проверяю, вот http://ree.su/test.html , посмотрите

Comment: У вас сейчас `ondragenter="allowDrop(event)"` в  `ev.preventDefault();` не срабатывает. Напишите другую функцию, которая всегда будет делать `ev.preventDefault()` без условий и поставьте ее на `ondragenter`

Comment: судя по всему drag&drop не поддерживаются на мобильных устройствах, нужно либо самому добавлять поддержку используя touch события, либо воспользоваться какой-либо существующей библиотекой

Comment: Использую этот скрипт: https://github.com/Bernardo-Castilho/dragdroptouch

Comment: Все перетаскивается, только не проверяется

Comment: @АндрейЗахаров, хм, не заметил, что ты уже используешь полифилл

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В подключенном полифилле, похоже, не совсем корректно обрабатывался вызов `preventDefault` внутри обработчиков события `dragover`, `dragenter`.

Если точнее - вообще не проверялось, что внутри этих обработчиков мог быть вызов `preventDefault` и, по умолчанию перетаскивать можно было везде.

---

```
if (target != this._lastTarget) {
    this._dispatchEvent(this._lastTouch, 'dragleave', this._lastTarget);
    this._dispatchEvent(e, 'dragenter', target);
    this._lastTarget = target;
}
```

В [форке](https://github.com/urffin/dragdroptouch) добавил проверку.

Пример:

```js
var dragged = null;

function allowDrop(ev) {
  if (ev.target.id == 'div' + dragged.id.match(/\d+/)) {
    ev.preventDefault();
  }
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
  dragged = ev.target;
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  dragged = null;
}
```

```css
div#div1 {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  min-width: 75px;
  min-height: 75px;
  background-color: red;
}

div#div2 {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  min-width: 75px;
  min-height: 75px;
  background-color: green;
}

div#div3 {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  min-width: 75px;
  min-height: 75px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawcdn.githack.com/urffin/dragdroptouch/bf3b3bc5da50d1909b5e5e7b2dc19a55e837f79c/DragDropTouch.js"></script>

<div style="overflow: hidden;">
  <div style="width: 100%;">
    <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div id="div3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<img id="drag1" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/188/188234.svg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="70" height="70">
<img id="drag2" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/188/188235.svg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="70" height="70">
<img id="drag3" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/188/188236.svg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="70" height="70">
```